# openssl Library not found

Tags: python, mysql, openssl, installation, homebrew

I've looked through dozens of posts about this and nothing seems to work so I think I'm just missing something but I'm doing a beginners tutorial on making a website using python so I'm not totally sure what I'm doing wrong. I did

```
    brew install mysql
```

and at the end of the install process I saw this: (I don't know if something was wrong at this point)

```
    /usr/bin/install_name_tool: object: /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.20_1/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib malformed object (unknown load command 9)
    /usr/bin/install_name_tool: object: /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.20_1/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib malformed object (unknown load command 9)
    ==> /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.20_1/bin/mysql_install_db --verbose --user=giancosta --basedir=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.20_1 --datadir=/usr/local/var/
    /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.20_1/bin/resolveip
    Please configure the 'hostname' command to return a correct
    hostname.
    If you want to solve this at a later stage, restart this script
    with the --force option
    Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
    You can try again using `brew postinstall mysql`
    ==> Summary
      /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.20_1: 9579 files, 342M
```

Then I did

```
    sudo easy_install mysql-python
```

which ended with: (again, I don't know if something was wrong at this point)

```
    20 warnings generated.
    ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.20_1/lib/libmysqlclient_r.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
    zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
    Adding MySQL-python 1.2.5 to easy-install.pth file

    Installed /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg
    Processing dependencies for mysql-python
    Finished processing dependencies for mysql-python
```

Finally I ran:

```
    mysqld
```

But I get:

```
    dyld: Library not loaded: @@HOMEBREW_PREFIX@@/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
    Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/mysqld
    Reason: image not found
    Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

So looking at other posts I tried removing or uninstalling openssl and then reinstalling it. But that's not working. I don't know what to do at this point. I've even tried uninstalling mysql to start over using

```
    sudo uninstall mysql
```

But that just gives me:

```
    Preparing Uninstall...
    Uninstall Began...
    Uninstall Failed...
    Reason: ErrorMissingBundle
```

I'm a beginner so I really don't know what to do/what's wrong at this point. Do I need to start over? If so, how? I've read posts that talk about links and OpenSSL messing things up, etc. but this is pretty foreign to me at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using pip (A tool for installing and managing Python packages) to install it.

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

Comment: So I did 'sudo pip uninstall MySQL-python' and then used the command you said, and still got the Load error I showed above when I try to do 'mysqld'

Comment: what version of python are you running?

Comment: I'm running python 2.7.6